# In SQL, how to delete a row from one table if it doesn't have a corresponding row in another table?

Tags: sql

How can I make:

DELETE FROM foo WHERE id=1 AND **bar not contains id==1**

To elaborate, how can I remove a row with `id = 1`, from table `foo`, only if there is not a row in table `bar` with `id = 1`.

Comment: I think you need to give more details.  the ->bar not contains id==1
doesn't seem understandable to me.

Comment: Is bar just another column or table?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id=1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bar WHERE id=1)
```

I'm assuming you mean that foo and bar are tables, and you want to remove a record from foo if it doesn't exist in bar.

Answer (score 11):

using a join:

```
delete f
from   foo f
left
join   bar b on
       f.id = b.id 
where  f.id = 1 and
       b.id is null
```

Comment: To my knowledge, only SQL Server and MySQL support that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL "Exists" command.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php